# check the tomcat running or not?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Tomcat running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944157/is-tomcat-running)

hi,

i installed tomcat server in virtual machine. i want to check the tomcat server daily, it is running or not. if it is running or not it will send mail to my mail id. how i achieve?

can i do this one by using batch files

Thanks
Murali

Answer (score 5):

You can cron the following script which checks the status of the tomcat pid present in the $CATALINA_PID file. If the pid is dead, an email is sent.

```
kill -0 `cat $CATALINA_PID` > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "Check tomcat" | mailx -s "Tomcat not running" support@dom.com
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple answers to this, depending on what you mean by "running".  For instance, @dogbane's answer tells you if a Tomcat process exists (modulo edge cases), and @Prabhakaran's answer tells you if Tomcat is listening on port 8080 (modulo different edge cases).  But neither of these will pick up cases where Tomcat has stopped responding to requests.

@Elite's answer tells you if the default (e.g. ROOT) servlet is running, but this is probably not enough.

I'd recommend the following approach:

- Pick some webapp pages that you care about.  Ideally these should include pages that depend on back-end services / databases.
- Create request URLs to fetch the pages, perform the queries, or whatever/
- Use `curl` or `wget` to send the request URLs.
- Use some kind of pattern matching to make sure that you are getting good results and not error pages.
- If you get timeouts, unexpected response codes or error pages, crank out a mail message<sup>1</sup>.

This kind of thing is easier to do if you are running on a UNIX / Linux platform than on Windows because the tools you need to implement it should be either installed already, or easy to install using the package manager.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, that's a recipe for spamming yourself.  A better idea is to deploy an event monitoring system that understands system states, does duplicate suppression and so on.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If tomcat is running, the easiest way (platform independent) is to type this url to any web browser (assuming your http port is configured to "80"): http://localhost:8080/. You can change localhost to any host server of choice. This will open a Tomcat page with the following message:

> **If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup Tomcat
>   successfully. Congratulations!**

Otherwise netstat and see if anything runs on port 8080.

---

**PS** I just read that you want to send email notification if not running, the best way is to create a job that periodically 1) listens to port 8080 or 2) find if a tomcat process is up and running. Failure to meet 1) or 2) sends an email to system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

if your tomcat is in linux environment then you can use netstat command to check for the tomcat listening port 8080 and send mail using shell script