# How to get serever Status of localhost(tomcat)?

Tags: java, localhost, status

I need to know the status of a Tomcat server (http://localhost:8081) - whether or not it is started using Java code. How can I do this if it is possible?

Comment: may be you can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095840/check-the-tomcat-running-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

Add a Tomcat Manager application and use GET urls, then parse the returned text.

You may read: 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html