# How to check if Tomcat Web Application is running and redirect to another server if there is an error?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, redirect

I have machine A running Apache 2.2 (acting as load balancer) and 2 machines(B & C) both running Tomcat and Java Web Application on Windows 7 in a network. Is there any way I can check:

1. If the Web application is down but the Tomcat is still running on Machine B and redirect the request to Machine C

Does this has to do with modifying the Tomcat or Apache 2.2 config? I have read [Is Tomcat running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944157/is-tomcat-running) but couldnt find any information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you can install a linux or cygwin, you can use varnish : https://www.varnish-cache.org/
and create a probe on our WebApp with 2 backends.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a load balancer (you can tell the load balancer to use a http health monitor vs tcp monitor). Unfortunately, Apache+tomcat only performs a tcp check and hence cannot tell if only the app is down. But if you find something, please share as this issue has been bugging me for a few years now !

Answer (score 0):

Try with a rest endpoint. If the rest endpoint is available the application is running.