# How to see tomcat is running or not

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, jvm

Which command is used to find tomcat is running or not in windows?

How do we know if JVM crashes suddenly?

After googling I posted it, I am not able to find expected result.

Answer (score 15):

Go to the start menu. Open up cmd (command prompt) and type in the following.

> wmic process list brief | find /i "tomcat"

This would tell you if the tomcat is running or not.

Comment: It doesn't show any thing after I add **wmic process list brief | find /i "tomcat.exe"** after that command prompt open and close suddenly

Comment: That means, your tomcat is not running.

And for future references avoid adding the extension while you run the command. It will then give you associated programs as well.

Answer (score 9):

open http://localhost:8080/ in browser, if you get tomcat home page. it means tomcat is running

Comment: It keeps on loading... in background logs no error thrown it is problem.

Comment: lunch  tomcat\bin\shutdown
and then lunch tomcat\bin\startup 
you will get a consol witch tell you if There is a problem

Comment: I already did it but it not shows any error

Comment: if I see a 404 error , what on opening that link, what does it mean?

Comment: but that is not always right , port can be configured in server.xml, like in my case

Answer (score 2):

open your browser,check whether Tomcat homepage is visible by below command.

```
http://ipaddress:portnumber
```

also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944157/is-tomcat-running)

Answer (score 0):

for localhost，the defaut port is 8080,you can test the link http://localhost:8080 in you browser.if you can see tomcat home page,your tomcat is running