# Changing of location of catalina.pid for tomcat

Tags: tomcat, catalina

"catalina.pid" is not in the "tomcat/bin" folders where it should be and it isn't created there during tomcat starting.
The question is how (where) i can redefine path to "catalina.pid" to force it to be created in a right folder.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 13):

Depending on the installation of tomcat, I have seen instances where catalina.pid is not defined. In this case, shut down tomcat, and define it yourself thusly:

In tomcat/bin/setenv.sh, add this line:

`CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE/bin/catalina.pid"`

or for windows (in setenv.bat): `set CATALINA_PID=%CATALINA_HOME%/bin/catalina.pid`

This will define and create the pid file in the tomcat/bin folder, assuming your CATALINA_HOME is defined as your tomcat folder. However, you may also change the location of the pid file, by just changing the path above.

Comment: doesn't work on Windows (but with cygwin). See http://pub.admc.com/howtos/tomcat/ch05.html

Comment: I was speaking of tomcat7, which will use a setenv file. I have no experience with tomcat 5/5.5, which is what your doc refers to. Thanks, though. I'll try to update the answer with versions later. (When I'm not on my phone).

Comment: Usage of CATALINA_PID variable is described in RUNNING.txt help file from tomcat distributive

Answer (score 2):

It's will be in the "temp"

```
/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid"
```