# tomcat service getting error and having contionous Syslog

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

One of my server is running with tomcat for a java application. The application is working fine with tomcat but in syslog we are getting the following error continuously in Ubuntu:

```
Oct 15 16:00:18 HiT-APP-Primary shutdown.sh[115760]: PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted.
Oct 15 16:00:18 HiT-APP-Primary systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 15 16:00:18 HiT-APP-Primary systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 15 16:00:18 HiT-APP-Primary systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 15 16:00:28 HiT-APP-Primary systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 15 16:00:28 HiT-APP-Primary systemd[1]: Stopped Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Oct 15 16:00:28 HiT-APP-Primary systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
Oct 15 16:00:28 HiT-APP-Primary startup.sh[115772]: Existing PID file found during start.
Oct 15 16:00:28 HiT-APP-Primary startup.sh[115772]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Oct 15 16:00:28 HiT-APP-Primary startup.sh[115772]: Tomcat started.
Oct 15 16:00:28 HiT-APP-Primary systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Oct 15 16:00:35 HiT-APP-Primary shutdown.sh[115867]: PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted.
Oct 15 16:00:35 HiT-APP-Primary systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 15 16:00:35 HiT-APP-Primary systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 15 16:00:35 HiT-APP-Primary systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Can anyone solve it please?

Answer (score 1):

in my case java home was not properly setup in tomcat service file to make this fixed open tomcat service file.

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
```

and verify JAVA_HOME is pointing to the correct JRE version if not then make it correct

```
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre"
```

After this reload daemon and start service again

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
Oct 15 16:00:18 HiT-APP-Primary shutdown.sh[115760]: PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted.
```

Looks like a permission issue. Check the permissions.
Otherwise
set `CATALINA_PID=/tmp/tomcat.pid`, or to a directory where tomcat has access. Then restart tomcat.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply, I just have set 
export CATALINA_PID=/tmp/tomcat.pid 
but it shows 
$CATALINA_PID was set but the specified file does not exist. Is Tomcat running? Stop aborted.

Please guide me as I am very newbie in Tomcat

Comment: Here are some discussions regarding this. Please have a look - https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/issues/41, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777090/changing-of-location-of-catalina-pid-for-tomcat