# Unable to find PID of Tomcat (RHEL)

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat

I am Using Linux rhel6 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

I can access tomcat from browser at port 8080. I am trying get PID of this .

I tried all the folling command but unable to fing the PID

**lsof -i :8080**

no output

**netstat -tulpn | grep :8080**

no output

also there is no log nor any httpd process running.

Please help me the find this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can `curl http://localhost:8080/` and the `netstat` command above fails? Hmm. That does many any sense at all.

Comment: This is very strange issue for me, even after shutting down the server i can access the tomcat page. I cleaned my browser settings, cookies everything even then I am able to accessit.It is also accessiable from other computers. I tried traceroute that gives * *  timout message. Curl is also working.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong. What is the full URL are you using to access Tomcat's start page?

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat application uses Java so that's why there is no httpd process running:

According to the source posted below the PID is posted in a $CATALINA_PID file which means that all you need to do is read that file with (TomCat version 5 or higher)

```
 cat $CATALINA_PID
```

And that should post the PID.

Source:
[Is Tomcat running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944157/is-tomcat-running)

Answer (score 0):

I use to find open ports programs like this:

```
# lsof -i -n -P | grep LIST | grep 8080
python    10335      xxxxxxxxx    3u  IPv4 10663405      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

The PID is usually defined in the init script. So you should take a look at

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat
```

Many init scripts seem to use this command for `$PID`:

```
ps aux | grep org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

`echo $CATALINA_PID` will only return the PID if `$CATALINA_PID` which is not necassary the case.

[source for init](https://gist.github.com/valotas/1000094)